# jQuery detect div (text/value) changes when Ajax pulls new data

Tags: jquery, real-time

Ok, I have now a big headache and trying to solve this for a few days but no success. I have an Ajax function that is within the setInterval and pulls in a new data from database every 2 seconds.

The Ajax creates a 'div' with the dynamic data coming from database as some numbers. Now, what i would like to implement is that when the new data is pulled or the text or value in DOM changes I want that particular div to do some animation.

Let's say it will change the background color to red and then reverse to the default color or the div border will flickr for three times, etc.. Somehow I cannot get this work. And i tried different Event listeners but no luck.

Here's my code for Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {



             //function the get data from database
             function getRealData() {
                 $.ajax({
                     url: 'test_api.php',
                     data: "",
                     dataType: 'json',
                     success: function (rows) {

                         var text = '';

                         var text2 = '';

                         for (var i in rows) {

                             var row = rows[i];


                             var timeRespons = row[4];

                             text+= '<div class="square"><h4>Time Response: '+ timeRespons+'</h4>';

                             text += '</div>';

                             }

                         $("#journey").html(text);

                        }
                 });


             }

             //this refreshes data every 2seconds
             setInterval(getRealData, 2000);

             //call the function to display data
             getRealData();

   });
```

and here's the output:[image]

So let's say if the time response change, then make the background red for 2 seconds and then reverse it back.
Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: Well, you are already creating the new div inside the ajax.success callback and that is the perfect place to check for any conditions for your animation. If you decided that you should animate just apply the animation to the div you just created.

Comment: Yes, but my Ajax function is constantly creating the div. So your solution would always animate the div even though there is no change in the value. I would like to animate the div only if the value has changed otherwise no animation.

Comment: No my solution wouldn't always animate the div. Like I said "... ajax.success callback is the perfect place **to check** for any **conditions** for your animation. **If you decide that you should animate** just apply the animation to the div you just created".

Comment: If you are comparing values between requests then you just need to keep a copy of the last response and compare the values when you get the new response. And if different (or any other condition) add any necessary animations to that specific div.

Comment: yes, you're right. but how do I do it? :( But keep in mind that the whole function is within the setinterval.

Comment: When navigating to this page/loading, you could consider creating javascript models/members for each of your controls. These models could include a `lastResponse` property, which you would just need to update. Ex. `var timer1, timer2, timer3` then `timer1.lastResponse`. It looks like you're missing some pieces in your overall design here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a `lastTimeResponse` variable in the scope of the function passed to `$(document).ready()`, which through closure would remain available to the `getRealData()` function. Something like this (added lines with comments):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // add a variable that remains through closure
    var lastTimeResponse = [];

    function getRealData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test_api.php',
            data: "",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (rows) {
                var changedRows = [];
                var text = '';
                var text2 = '';
                for (var i in rows) {
                    var row = rows[i];
                    var timeRespons = row[4];
                    text += '<div class="square r'+i+'"><h4>Time Response: '+ timeRespons+'</h4>';
                    text += '</div>';
                    // check the conditions for animation to happen
                    if (lastTimeResponse[i] !== timeRespons)
                    {
                        changedRows.push(i);
                    }

                    // store the most recent value
                    lastTimeResponse[i] = timeRespons;
                }
                $("#journey").html(text);
                for (var j=0; j<changedRows.length; j+=1)
                {
                    $(".square.r"+changedRows[j]).animate(/*your animation here*/);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //this refreshes data every 2seconds
    setInterval(getRealData, 2000);

    //call the function to display data
    getRealData();

});
```

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. Although it works only if I change the last value form the database. So for example when Time Response: 0.224 has changed then it does the animation (but to all DIVS instead of just that particular one), but when I change any other value it does not work. It seems like it is picking only very last element from the array.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. Updated to keep a lastTimeResponse per row, assuming you will have a constant number of rows in the same order.

Comment: Cool..I've put the following into your solution: $(".square").animate({"background-color":"red"},200);
$(".square").animate({"background-color":"white"},200); But it does not work. When I change it to apply to $("body") then body flickers 6 times :)

Comment: Yes, in fact the text is only written into the DOM after all the checking is done, so trying to animate them where I've put the comment doesn't work. Perhaps if you create an array of the indexes (values of `i`) for rows which have changed, and then after `$("#journey").html(text);` you can loop through `$("#journey .square") and trigger the animation for each index in that array? Changed answer to illustrate that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare values between responses then you can create a local variable that always stores the last response.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lastResponse = null;
```

On each successful AJAX response you compare the new response with the last response and decide if it's necessary to animate any of the new divs.

```
success: function (rows) {

    var text = '';
    var text2 = '';
    for (var i in rows) {
        var row = rows[i];
        var timeRespons = row[4];
        if (lastResponse && lastResponse[i][4] !== timeRespons)
        {
            // this specific 'row' has a different value than last time
            text += '<div class="square" style="background-color:red;"><h4>Time Response *changed*: '+ timeRespons+'</h4></div>';
        }
        else
        {
            // otherwise
            text += '<div class="square"><h4>Time Response: '+ timeRespons+'</h4></div>';
        }
    }

    $("#journey").html(text);

    // save this response as last response
    lastResponse = rows;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. Although it works only if I change the last value form the database. So for example when Time Response: 0.224 has changed then it does the animation (but to all DIVS instead of just that particular one), but when I change any other value it does not work. It seems like it is picking only very last element from the array.

Comment: @Marcel: have you tried the last edit? This code should be div specific.

Comment: That works just brilliant. But how can make more flexible, etc..adding some animations to it. As you solution writes Time Response *changed* but quickly reverts back to Time Response after 2 secs.

Comment: @Marcel: Yes that was just as an example. If you want to change the background color then you could use a new CSS class to say that it's a different color. If you would like some timed animations then you would need to make the new div as a jQuery object and apply those animations to it. See the edit, I added an inline style wiht red background to it.

Comment: +1, same as mine but caching the entire response rather than just the response times. Either is good, I think.